# ANTLR toStringTree() not being recognised

Tags: java, antlr

I'm using antlr to write a grammar, and I have a main function to test the programs accepted by the grammar. The main function is:

```
package compiler;
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        SmallCLexer lexer = new SmallCLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        SmallCParser parser = new SmallCParser(tokens);
        SmallCParser.program_return result = parser.program();
        String tree = result.tree.toStringTree();
        System.out.println(tree);
    }
}
```

My problem is that it's not recognising the toStringTree() command and I was wondering if anyone could see why?

I found this:
http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/interfaceorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1tree_1_1_tree.html

Which claims that the function is contained in BaseTree.

I also edited my code to import all of the antlr files with org.antlr.runtime.* but this still doesn't fix this. I just don't understand why it can't recognise it.

Comment: Why the throw exception in the main method?

Comment: Honestly it's from some sample code I was using to learn how to write this, I wasn't sure why it was there but I didn't see any harm in leaving it in. I've just tried it without it and it doesn't change it. :(

Comment: Where is the information that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Well right now it's just whatever I type into the console (although I also tried to do it by typing in a predefined string), the problem is it isn't even reaching that, it's just not importing the function for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the import:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree;
```

and then try this:

```
CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.program().getTree();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree());
```

Note that this will only work if your have the following option in your parser grammar:

```
options {
  output=AST;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I actually just managed to get it working. The code I changed was:
  String tree = ((Tree)result.tree).toStringTree();
  System.out.println(tree);

I'm not sure if your way is better or not, do you know why it is that mine worked?

Comment: @Incredidave, it's pretty much the same: a `CommonTree` extends a `Tree`. And `.tree` and `.getTree()` return the same object.

Comment: Ah, cool. I've selected you as the right answer then. Thanks!